# Feedparser only returns number not the entire URL

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

I am using a simple Python script to retrieve the latest RSS info

```
# RSS read 
d = feedparser.parse("http://rss.kicker.de/news/wm")
### (1) Last RSS Feed
url = d.entries[1].id
```

It works fine as in above with i.e. 
http://rss.kicker.de/news/f1news
Result: http://www.kicker.de/news/formel1/startseite/727510/artikel_vettel-jetzt-auf-augenhoehe-mit-hamilton.html#omrss

Not working:
https://www.fia.com/rss/news/
Result: 23278 at https://www.fia.com

What am I doing wrong here?

Regards,
ET

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the `d.entries[1].id` return this tag (I believe it's because the `id` returns the unique identifier of the `entries`) :

```
<guid isPermaLink="false">23278 at https://www.fia.com</guid>
```

If you want to take the url, you can use:

```
d.entries[1]['link']
```

References:

- [Doc for id](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/reference-entry-id.html)
- [Doc for link](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/reference-entry-link.html)